# Angularjs - Reload scope with new data from database

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, filter, scope

I am building a search page using Angularjs. Everything works fine but my concern is, what if a user adds a new entry into the database after the search page is already loaded? The new entry does not show up on filter. How to achieve this? Below is my code. Any help is appreciated.

```
var app = angular.module('searchApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        if(input) {
            start = +start; //parse to int
            return input.slice(start);
        }
        return [];
    }
});
app.controller('searchCrtl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.showLoader = true;
    $http.get('PostsController.do?cmd=postDetails').success(function(data){
        $scope.showLoader = false;

        $scope.list = data;
        $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
        $scope.entryLimit = 10000; //max no of items to display in a page
        $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length; //Initially for no filter  
        $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;
    });
    $scope.setPage = function(pageNo) {
        $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
    };
    $scope.filter = function() {
        $timeout(function() { 
            console.log($scope.list);
            $scope.filteredItems = $scope.filtered.length;
        }, 10);
    };
    $scope.sort_by = function(predicate) {
        $scope.predicate = predicate;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    };
});
```

Is there a way to make the scope load with new data from database on filtering items?

Comment: New data from database? You may need websocket to get notified when database is updated

Comment: How to use it? Con you give me some links/

Comment: Unlike Http, Websocket enables backend servers and client browsers to communicate as long as they want without creating new connections.  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) has the best documentation. You may not need it since it consumes many resources,  unless you need it to be real-time

Comment: I just need it for a small application. You have any tutorial links on how to use it with angularjs?

Comment: Does your server support websocket? If not yet, I suggest you going with good old [long polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling)

Comment: I am creating a dynamic web project using eclipse and apache tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

A tmp workaround is to query server every 10s. You still need to learn what websocket is, what it is used for and how you can use it in backend and frontend.

```
app.controller('searchCrtl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.showLoader = true;

    // <--
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.entryLimit = 10000;
    setInterval(function () {
        $http.get('PostsController.do?cmd=postDetails').success(function(data){
            $scope.showLoader = false;
            $scope.list = data;
            $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length; //Initially for no filter  
            $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;
        });
    }, 10000);  // update data every 10 sec
    // -->


    $scope.setPage = function(pageNo) {
        $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
    };
    $scope.filter = function() {
        $timeout(function() { 
            console.log($scope.list);
            $scope.filteredItems = $scope.filtered.length;
        }, 10);
    };
    $scope.sort_by = function(predicate) {
        $scope.predicate = predicate;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    };
});
```